# Importing members in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.9.x I was used to the following syntax:

```
class B(currencies: Seq[Currency])(implicit c:C)  extends
CSomething(c){
import c._
 // def mystuff = call() // in fact this is c.call()
}
```

This does not work anymore in Scala 2.10.x, meaning that if I do import c._ , the members of c are not visible inside B. I am therefore forced to do c.call().

Is members importing forbidden in Scala 2.10.x? why?

Comment: It certainly **does** work in 2.10.x, so you probably have a more specific problem. Can you post a complete code snippet that reproduces the error?